# R: Align Text Ouput Next to Plot Output in html knitr File

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, plotly

I'd like to align some text output next to a plot output from plotly in an html knitr file. For example, I'd like the output of the functions below to appear side by side in the document.

````
---
title: 'untitled'
output: html_document
---

```{r}
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, plotly, grid, gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(y = var1, x = 
var2, color = p_c)) + geom_point(aes(text = subjID)) + 
geom_smooth(method = "lm") 

ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text")
cor.test(var1, var2)
```
````

I've fooled around with Grobs (i.e. grobText) and the grid/gridExtra packages - but those don't seem compatible with plotly. For example:

````
```{r}
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, plotly, grid, gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(y = var1, x = 
var2, color = p_c)) + geom_point(aes(text = subjID)) + 
geom_smooth(method = "lm") 

p1 <- ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text")
text1 <- cor.test(var1, var2)

text1 <- textGrob(text1)

grid.arrange(p1, text1, ncol = 2)
```
````

This returns the error: Error in gList(list(x = list(data = list(list(x = c(-28, 1689, 1122, 284,  : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

I've also considered flexdashboard, but I don't want the output to appear in a separate html page from the rest of the report.

Any thoughts are appreciated, especially if there's a way to get the row formatting of flexdashboard to be inserted into the middle of a standard html rmarkdown file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MLavoie I'm not sure which part is flouting the MCV rule of thumb. Can you be more specific so I can ask better questions?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible; we can't run test code!

Comment: @MLavoie, Thank you! Tried to improve.